# How do you sort AMIs by the CreationDate string in Boto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Using Boto I have:

```
images = ec2_client.describe_images(
    Owners=['self']
)
```

How do I sort these images using the CreationDate key?

When I try to use:

```
print({image['CreationDate']: image['ImageId'] in sorted(images.items(), key=lambda image: image['CreationDate'])})
```

I get `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`

which I assume is because the CreationDate is a string.

Maybe there's some Python library to convert?

Comment: What output are you seeking? It appears that you want to create a dictionary with the Key being the creation date and the Value being in the Image ID? Or do you simply want Image ID in date order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `image` is not defined, so it will not even run. Also `images.items()` is incorrect. So your script fails not because the `CreationDate` is string. It should be:

```
print({image['CreationDate']: image['ImageId'] for image in sorted(images['Images'], key=lambda image: image['CreationDate'])})
```

Also `CreationDate` is in the format which allows it to be sorted as string. But if you really want to parse the string into `datetime` then you can do:

```
from datetime import datetime
print({image['CreationDate']: image['ImageId'] for image in sorted(images['Images'], key=lambda image: datetime.strptime(image['CreationDate'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'))})
```